# Как получить пригласительную ссылку по которой вступил участник канала Aiogram?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Перечитал уже и про ChatJoinRequest и про ChatMemberUpdated, ничего не могу найти
При использовании

```
async def join_request(update: types.ChatJoinRequest):
    print(update.invite_link)
```

Пишет ошибку

```
ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-7' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:407> exception=OSError(22, 'Invalid argument')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 311, in process_update
    return await self.chat_join_request_handlers.notify(update.chat_join_request)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Py\apiconversions\apifb.py", line 26, in join_request
    print(update.invite_link)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\types\base.py", line 212, in __str__
    return self.as_json()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\types\base.py", line 200, in as_json
    return json.dumps(self.to_python())
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\types\base.py", line 177, in to_python
    value = self.props[name].export(self)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\types\fields.py", line 95, in export
    return self.serialize(self.get_value(instance))
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\types\fields.py", line 172, in serialize
    return round(value.timestamp())
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел. Пригласительная в

```
update.invite_link.invite_link
```